# grep ipaddress from file in expect script

Tags: expect

this is the code, and I'm stuck in the line where I need to grep IP address from file $filename, 
        #!/usr/local/bin/expect -- 
    ###Made by Etihkru####

```
set env(TERM) vt100
set env(SHELL) /bin/sh
set env(HOME) /usr/local/bin

set PASSWORD er
set SIU [lindex $argv 0]
exp_internal 1
spawn ssh mashost
set USER admin
set PASS hidden

expect {
    "assword"  {send "$PASSWORD\r"}
}

        expect "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
        send -- "cd /var/opt/bla/edd/ARNE_SIU \r"
        expect "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
        send -- "grep -il $SIU *\r"
        set prompt {ranosusr@rn2osscs603> }
        expect -re "($SIU\\S+\\.xml).*$prompt$"
        set filename $expect_out(1,string)  
        send -- "/opt/ericsson/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -val:rall\r"
        expect "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
        send -- "/opt/ericsson/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import\r"
        expect "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
        send -- "cat $filename | grep {1,3\}\.\{1,3\}\.\{1,3\}\.\{1,3\} \r"
        expect -re "{1,3\}\.\{1,3\}\.\{1,3\}\.\{1,3\}" *$prompt$"
        set IP $expect_out(1,string)
        sleep 10s

spawn ssh admin@$IP
expect {
    -re "RSA key fingerprint" {send "yes\r"}
    timeout {puts "Host is known"}
}

expect {
    "assword"  {send "$PASS\r"}
}

expect "Osmon>"
send -- "resumePMMeasurements STN=0,MeasurementDefinition=0 sftp://pmup-rn2sossv605:er@10.211.149.60/GRAN/rn2sossv605/$SIU/NeTransientUp \r"
expect "Osmon>"
send -- "getalarmlist \r"
expect -re "(\Operation Succeed\)"
send -- "rev \r"
expect "Osmon>"
send -- "subscribe 10.211.149.40 1 \r"
expect "Osmon>"
send -- "getsubscriptionstatus 1 \r"
expect "Osmon>"
interact
```

the output is :

```
perl siu1 FRTAMX
spawn ssh mashost
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {1162}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword"? no

expect: does "\r\n|-----------------------------------------------------------------|\r\n| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |\r\n| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |\r\n| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |\r\n| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |\r\n| personnel.                                                      |\r\n|                                                                 |\r\n| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |\r\n| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |\r\n| of authorized users may also be monitored.                    |\r\n|                                                                 |\r\n| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |\r\n| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |\r\n| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |\r\n| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |\r\n|-----------------------------------------------------------------|\r\n\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword"? no
Password:
expect: does "\r\n|-----------------------------------------------------------------|\r\n| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |\r\n| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |\r\n| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |\r\n| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |\r\n| personnel.                                                      |\r\n|                                                                 |\r\n| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |\r\n| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |\r\n| of authorized users may also be monitored.                    |\r\n|                                                                 |\r\n| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |\r\n| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |\r\n| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |\r\n| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |\r\n|-----------------------------------------------------------------|\r\n\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "assword"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n|-----------------------------------------------------------------|\r\n| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |\r\n| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |\r\n| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |\r\n| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |\r\n| personnel.                                                      |\r\n| |\r\n| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |\r\n| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |\r\n| of authorized users may also be monitored.                      |\r\n|                                                                 |\r\n| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |\r\n| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |\r\n| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |\r\n| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |\r\n|-----------------------------------------------------------------|\r\n\r\nPassword"
send: sending "bla\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does ": " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no


expect: does ": \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
Last login: Wed Mar 12 15:42:34 2014 from rn2sosas601

expect: does ": \r\nLast login: Wed Mar 12 15:42:34 2014 from rn2sosas601\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
You have new mail.

expect: does ": \r\nLast login: Wed Mar 12 15:42:34 2014 from rn2sosas601\r\r\nYou have new mail.\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
ranosusr@rn2osscs603>
expect: does ": \r\nLast login: Wed Mar 12 15:42:34 2014 from rn2sosas601\r\r\nYou have new mail.\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ": \r\nLast login: Wed Mar 12 15:42:34 2014 from rn2sosas601\r\r\nYou have new mail.\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603"
send: sending "cd /var/opt/bla/edd/ARNE_SIU \r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
cd /var/opt/e
expect: does "> cd /var/opt/e" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
ricsson/edd
expect: does "> cd /var/opt/bla/edd" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
/ARNE_SIU

expect: does "> cd /var/opt/bla/edd/ARNE_SIU \r\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
ranosusr@rn2osscs603>
expect: does "> cd /var/opt/bla/edd/ARNE_SIU \r\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "> cd /var/opt/bla/edd/ARNE_SIU \r\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603"
send: sending "grep -il FRTAMX *\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "> " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(FRTAMX\S+\.xml).*ranosusr@rn2osscs603> $"? no
grep -il FRTAMX *

expect: does "> grep -il FRTAMX *\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(FRTAMX\S+\.xml).*ranosusr@rn2osscs603> $"? no
FXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml
FXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE_upgraded_temp.xml

expect: does "> grep -il FRTAMX *\r\r\nFXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml\r\nFXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE_upgraded_temp.xml\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(FRTAMX\S+\.xml).*ranosusr@rn2osscs603> $"? no
ranosusr@rn2osscs603>
expect: does "> grep -il FRTAMX *\r\r\nFXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml\r\nFXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE_upgraded_temp.xml\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603> " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(FRTAMX\S+\.xml).*ranosusr@rn2osscs603> $"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml\r\nFXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE_upgraded_temp.xml\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603> "
expect: set expect_out(1,string) "FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "> grep -il FRTAMX *\r\r\nFXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml\r\nFXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE_upgraded_temp.xml\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603> "
send: sending "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -val:rall\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh
expect: does "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
 -f  -val:rall

expect: does "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -val:rall\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
Logging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:36

expect: does "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -val:rall\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:36\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
Failed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.
The file '-val:rall' can not be found.

expect: does "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -val:rall\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:36\r\nFailed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.\r\nThe file '-val:rall' can not be found.\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
ranosusr@rn2osscs603>
expect: does "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -val:rall\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:36\r\nFailed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.\r\nThe file '-val:rall' can not be found.\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -val:rall\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:36\r\nFailed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.\r\nThe file '-val:rall' can not be found.\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603"
send: sending "/opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
/opt/ericsso
expect: does "> /opt/ericsso" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
n/arn
expect: does "> /opt/bla/arn" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
e/bin/import.sh -f
expect: does "> /opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
  -import
expect: does "> /opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no


expect: does "> /opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
Logging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:40

expect: does "> /opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:40\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
Failed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.
The file '-import' can not be found.

expect: does "> /opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:40\r\nFailed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.\r\nThe file '-import' can not be found.\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? no
ranosusr@rn2osscs603>
expect: does "> /opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:40\r\nFailed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.\r\nThe file '-import' can not be found.\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "ranosusr@rn2osscs603"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "> /opt/bla/arne/bin/import.sh -f  -import\r\r\nLogging to file /var/opt/bla/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2014-03-12_15:43:40\r\nFailed to write to file. Writing to stdout instead.\r\nThe file '-import' can not be found.\r\nranosusr@rn2osscs603"
send: sending "cat FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml | grep {1,3}.{1,3}.{1,3}.{1,3} \r" to { exp4 }
couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid
    while executing
"expect -re "{1,3\}\.\{1,3\}\.\{1,3\}\.\{1,3\}" *$prompt$""
    (file "siu1" line 32)
ranosusr@rn2sosas601>
```

sory for the big ouput, but this is what I got with `exp_internal 1`. So the problem is with grepin Ip address, some commands I have disabled in code, to be faster until I manage the ipaddress. Thanks

Comment: Before you automate something via expect, you need to make sure it works. Like if you manually issue the commands, output will be as deired/expected. It seems to me that is not the case here... you have multiple error messages intertwined in your expect output above. Both import.sh calls complain profusely, and so does your grep command. I think you have some work to do before you try to put all that in an expect script.

Comment: the import commands I have disabled, because they are running some commands which I want to avoid at the moment, because I test this grep every few minutes, so like I said in Question above, you can ignore this import, and vall:rall command. Only problem is with grep line, for now:)

Comment: anybody???...I'm on deadline, a little bit:(

Comment: question also appears on http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119522/4667

Comment: Your use of grep is flawed, as well as the regexp used. Use egrep if you need to match with regular expressions. The below will return lines with IP addresses, although lines with invalid IP addresses will be returned as well (like 300.300.300.300). If you google you can find much better matches for valid IP addresses.
`egrep "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}" FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml`
Use a similar regexp to match the IP address itself (as opposed to the line returned by egrep) in the expect statement.

Comment: unfortunatly guys still is not worknig. My grep doesn't support -o, -P , I tried egrep and say [0-9] invalid command name.  @glenn_jackmann I edit a question, I suceed to grep this  a string with ip address, but now I need to remove some caracters....unix.stackexchange.com/q/119522/4667